# Can you transfer an Apple TV and iOS App to another Developer Account?

Tags: ios, tvos

Is there an option for an iOS app to be transferred to another Apple Developer account after it goes live and can an Apple TV app be transferred as well?

As this is my first time, I am developing app for TVOS and my clients want this option.

Comment: May be [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3784854?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) link helpful

Comment: @Mahesh.D
The above link is for end users. My question is related to Developer account, I know that iOS app is transferable but there are no mention of Apple TV app.

https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deve445a9a11

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Follow the instruction on [this site](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deved688524f). You need to make sure that your apps meets the criteria outline [here](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devaf27784ff).